# Why does passing an unsigned int to performSelector lose bits?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to pass a hex value as an unsigned int to a method using a dynamic link. The value I pass as a parameter is getting corrupted somehow. What is happening?

```
- (void)callPerformSelector
{
    NSNumber *argument = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:(unsigned int)0xFFFFFFFF];
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"testPerformSelector:");
    NSLog(@"testPerformSelector object %@", argument);
   [self performSelector:selector withObject:argument];
}

- (void)testPerformSelector:(unsigned int) arg1
{
    NSLog(@"testPerformSelector unsigned int %u", arg1);
    NSLog(@"testPerformSelector hex %X", arg1);
}
```

Output is:

```
testPerformSelector object 4294967295
testPerformSelector unsigned int 4294967283
testPerformSelector hex FFFFFFF3
```

Answer (score 5):

Because it should be:

```
- (void)callPerformSelector
{
    NSNumber *argument = @0xFFFFFFFF;
    SEL selector = @selector(testPerformSelector:);
    NSLog(@"testPerformSelector object %@", argument);
   [self performSelector:selector withObject:argument];
}

- (void)testPerformSelector:(NSNumber *) arg1
{
    NSLog(@"testPerformSelector unsigned int %u", arg1.unsignedIntValue);
}
```

`unsigned int` and `NSNumber *` is two different things

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy reason and a complex reason.

Simple reason: *Why this doesn't work*. The first argument to the target of a `performSelectorWithObject` must be an object. You are specifying a pointer to an unsigned integer in your function signature but then passing an object (`NSNumber`) when you call it. So instead of:

```
- (void)testPerformSelector:(unsigned int) arg1
```

you should have

```
- (void)testPerformSelector:(NSNumber *) arg1
```

You will then need to use `NSNumber`'s `unsignedIntValue` to get the `0xFFFFFFFF` out of the object.

The complex reason is much more interesting: *Why this nearly works and looks like it loses a few bits*. NSNumber is an object that wraps a numeric value this is very different from a raw numeric value. However NSNumber is implemented as a tagged pointer so although objective-c knows it is an object and treats it like an object, a subset of NSNumber values are implemented as tagged pointers where real values are coded into the "pointer" and the fact that this is not a normal pointer is indicated in the (otherwise always zero) bottom four bits of a pointer [see Friday Q&A](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass objects to selectors and not primitive types, and therefore the selector should be:

```
- (void)testPerformSelector:(NSNumber *) arg1
{
    NSLog(@"testPerformSelector hex %x", [arg1 unsignedIntValue]);
}
```

Update: As pointed-out by @gnasher729, the reason the number passed appears to be `-13` is because it's a [tagged pointer](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html).

Comment: It's a tagged pointer. What you see is the lower 24 bit of the number, followed by 8 bit of tag.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thanks.  Updated answer.