# Does passing an unsigned int to a function make it lose bits?

Tags: c, hex, bit-shift, unsigned, unsigned-integer

My question is quite similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40508865/8798229) except that I’m working with C.

I wrote some code to rotate an unsigned int; that is, the function `bitRotate()` (code below).

The function works very well when, instead of the `printf`s and `scanf`s, I directly put the literals I want to use, e.g. `bitRotate(0xabcdef00,8);`in the main function.

However, when I pass x as an argument as in the following code, abcdef00 that was got from the user, the x gets corrupted to ab000000. I checked and double checked and debugged my code multiple times and I am pretty sure the error is in this part but I don’t understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define WIDTH sizeof(unsigned int)*CHAR_BIT

unsigned int bitRotate(unsigned int, char );

int main()
{

    unsigned int x;
    char n;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter x: ");
        scanf("%x", &x);
        printf("Enter n: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("%x\n", bitRotate(x,n));
    }

    return 0;
}

unsigned int bitRotate(unsigned int value, char n)
{

    char un = abs(n);
    unsigned int fallen = ~(0u);

    if(un == WIDTH)
        return value;
    else if (un < WIDTH)
    {

        if (n < 0)
        {
            fallen >>= (WIDTH - n);
            fallen = value & fallen;
            fallen <<= (WIDTH - n);
            value >>= n;
        }
        else
        {
            fallen <<= (WIDTH - n);
            fallen = value & fallen;
            fallen >>= (WIDTH - n);
            value <<= n;
        }
        value |= fallen;
        return value;

    }
    else
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: `"%d"` is the wrong format specifier to input a `char` via `scanf`. You need to use `"%c"`,, and to consume the newline whitespace from the previous entry, I think you need to use `" %c"` (with a leading space). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer) question might be helpful.

Comment: At lease add `int response = getchar(); if(response == 'q') break;` to the end of your loop.

Comment: How did you verify that you read the correct numbers? You do not check the return value of `scanf` and you don't print your numbers. How would you notice an error before you call your rotating function?

Comment: Chances are good that your invalid format specifier for `scanf` leads to corruption of the number. Storing 4 or 8 bytes into a single character variable doesn't fit well.

Comment: @yano I changed the type of n to int at every instance but nothing changed. I just posted here the original code without the edits I made to find the error.

Comment: @Gerhardh i put “printf(“the number you entered was ...”). But like i said i only posted here the code without any of the debugging methods i used.

Comment: @ryyker well, yes but I found some sources saying that this is better “for portability reasons” so I just put it like that.. Maybe on some systems a byte isn’t 8 bits? I am not sure why they recommended doing so

Comment: @user401445 That's correct. I've never worked on a system that didn't have an 8-bit byte, but they do exist.

Comment: Checking return value is not a debugging method. You should print x and n after second scanf. BTW what ist exact input for scanf?

Comment: @user401445 - Yes, It had been awhile since I have seen `CHAR_BIT`, I removed the comment, and yes, it is correct to use it for what you are doing.  Sorry for the confusion on that.

Comment: @user401445 _" I changed the type of n to int at every instance but nothing changed"_: I don't believe you.

Comment: `char un = abs(n);` could be a problem.  this should be: `int un = abs(n);`

Comment: @ryyker not sure why char `un = abs(n)` could be a problem except when `n` is > 255, but for large values of `n` rotating doesn't make much sense anyway.

Comment: The code `if (n < 0)` relies on `char` being signed type which may or may not apply. You should use `signed char` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bitRotate` function is fine and so is the way you call it.

The actual culprit is here:

```
char n;
scanf("%d", &n);  // <<<<<
```

You provide the wrong format specifier to `scanf` which results in undefined behaviour. Your compiler most likely warned you about this.

The `%d` format specifier needs an pointer to an `int` (which usually takes 32 bits), but you provide the pointer to a `char` which takes 8 bits. Therefore `scanf` most likely clobbers the memory adjacent to the address of `n`.

You want this:

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
```

Comment: Oh well, there was one char which I didn't change.. You're right, the code worked. But I have a question, what if I don't need all of the bits of int?? I need to store an integeral value (i.e. not ASCII, if I enter 8 as the value for n at the console, I want it to be understood as 8 not as '8'), so %c won't work. What can I do instead?

Comment: @user401445 Use `%hhd` for the format specifier.  That expects the address of a `char`.

Comment: @dbush Hello, I was working on a new problem and I used the %hhd you suggested but the compiler (mingw on windows 10) gave me a warning. I googled a bit and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678124/mingw-gcc-unknown-conversion-type-character-h-snprintf). I tried the same idea with scanf (i.e. `_mingw_scanf()`) but it turns out that there is no function with that name. Do you have an idea how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: @user401445 please ask another question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behaviour.

In this call

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

you are using a wrong conversion specifier with an object of the type `char`. Moreover the type `char` can behave either as a `signed char` or as `unsigned char` depending on a compiler option.

Within the function there is used a wrong expression when n is negative

```
fallen >>= (WIDTH - n);
                 ^^^
fallen <<= (WIDTH - n);
                 ^^^
```

I think you mean

```
fallen >>= (WIDTH + n);
                 ^^^
fallen <<= (WIDTH + n);
                 ^^^
```

In any case the function can be written simpler. Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

unsigned int bitRotate(unsigned int value, int n )
{
    const int Width = sizeof( unsigned int ) * CHAR_BIT;

    n %= Width;

    if ( n < 0 )
    {
        value = ( value >> -n ) | ( value << ( Width + n ) );
    }
    else if ( n > 0 )
    {
        value = ( value << n ) | ( value >> ( Width - n ) );

    }

    return value;
}

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        unsigned int x;

        printf( "Enter a hexadecimal value of x (0 - exit): " );

        if ( scanf( "%x", &x ) != 1 || x == 0 ) break;

        int n;

        printf( "Enter a negative or positive value of n (0 - exit): " );
        if ( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        printf( "\n%#x shifted %d is %#x\n", x, n, bitRotate( x, n ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a hexadecimal value of x (0 - exit): 0xabcdef00
Enter a negative or positive value of n (0 - exit): 16

0xabcdef00 shifted 16 is 0xef00abcd

Enter a hexadecimal value of x (0 - exit): 0xabcdef00
Enter a negative or positive value of n (0 - exit): -16

0xabcdef00 shifted -16 is 0xef00abcd

Enter a hexadecimal value of x (0 - exit): 0xabcdef00
Enter a negative or positive value of n (0 - exit): 32

0xabcdef00 shifted 16 is 0xabcdef00

Enter a hexadecimal value of x (0 - exit): 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This code shows you if the value has the sign bit or not:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    const int arr[7] = {0x80000000u, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 0x7fffffffu};
    unsigned int i, j, signVal, uiSiz;

    uiSiz = sizeof(unsigned int);

    for (i = 0, j = 7; i < 7; i++) {
        signVal = ((unsigned int) arr[i] & (0x1u << ((8 * uiSiz) - 1))) >> ((8 * uiSiz) - 1);
        fprintf(stdout, "arr[%u]: %i, uiSiz: %u, signVal: %u;\n", i, arr[i], uiSiz, signVal);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

LINK @[ https://ideone.com/rWiSrF ]